# C# - Что использовать для десериализации Json в UWP приложениях?

Tags: c#, json, uwp

Всем привет! Для десериализации json в консольных приложений использовал библиотеку Newtonsoft.Json. Но в UWP приложениях она не устанавливается.
Что можно использовать для десериализации json в UWP приложениях написанных на C#?
Если не затруднит, то и пример работы.
ДОБ: Ошибка при добавления библиотеки Newtonsoft.Json в диспетчере пакетов Nuget:

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Comment: Как не устанавливается? Сам лично видел в курсе по UWP в Microsoft Virtual Academy как преподаватель ее подключал и использовал.

Comment: Опишите подробнее что вы конкретно пошаговое делаете и на каком моменте у вас возникает проблема.

Comment: @Андрей В диспетчере пакетов Nuget пишу:
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json. А потом не выдаёт ошибку установки

Comment: @Fooxboy: Опишите в точности вашу конфигурацию. Согласно [документации](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases), netstandard должен поддерживаться. Возможно, у вас нестандартная конфигурация.

Comment: @Fooxboy, похоже что у вас повреждены какие-то файлы проекта. Только что создал пустой Uwp App Blank и установил в него последнюю версию JSON.NET без проблем

Comment: @Андрей Спасибо. Попробую переустановить Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решилось переустановкой Visual Studio. Спасибо всем кто откликнулся!